# Comparative histogram of two data files, one with frequency, the other with boxes

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I have two sets of data, and aim to make a comparative histogram from them. However one is a two-column data, x and its frequency, the second one is a one-column unsorted data which gnuplot should derive out the frequencies. I want a continuous histogram, but whatever I find on the web has gaps.

how should I do this?

I tried using the following script

```
binwidth=5 
bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width) 
plot'data1.txt' with boxes, 'data2.txt' using (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq with boxes
```

with the data files `data1.txt`:

```
1 3    
5 1    
7 1
```

and the second data file `data2.txt`:

```
1    
1    
1    
5    
7
```

This doesn't give the expected result.

Comment: Please do not use your question to some kind of conversation. Its fine to expand it, but with your last edit you removed almost all of the actual content. I tried to edit the question so that one has all necessary information: data files and the script.

Comment: Now you must only explain what you mean with "doesn't work". Maybe you have only the wrong range settings. Add the lines `set yrange [0:*]; set offset 1,1,1,0;` before your script. I get the result http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ny0Gy.png That is continuous in the meaning, that the boxes have different widths, so that there is no gap between them. If you mean something else, you must be more precise (an example image...).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `smooth frequency` option, which makes the data monotonic in x; points with the same x-value are replaced by a single point having the summed y-values. So, if you use the first column as x-values and `1` as y-value you get the count:

```
plot 'secondfile.dat' using 1:(1) smooth frequency with linespoints
```

[image]

The plotting style is almost independent of the plotting style, so you can use points, lines, boxes etc.